# Trying to load a pcd file to rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saved a pcd file from rgbdslam `Save > Save as Point Cloud ...` and when I tried to `Load > Open PCD files` I get the following error:

```
 [ERROR] [1455205544.447237056]: Cloud has "flat" dimensions: 1 x 5305023
```

- *Ubuntu 14.04.5*
- *ROS Indigo*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226334/trying-to-load-a-pcd-file-to-rgbdslam/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: The saved cloud is the *map*, the load function loads individual *measurements*.

Details:

The load function takes a set of pcd files, each representing one sensor measurement and expects each to have the 2d raster layout of a depth image, e.g. 640x480.

The saved cloud is an aggregation of the point clouds in the map, transformed into a common coordinate frame (/map). Because of the aggregation, the raster layout is dropped and the cloud has "flat" dimensions.

The obvious next question is "*how do I load a map into rgbdslam*", e.g. to continue mapping. Unfortunately you can't, it's not implemented.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0